# How to dynamically create bootstrap modals as Angular2 components?

Tags: angular

**Original title**: Can't initialize dynamically appended (HTML) component in Angular 2

I've created a directive that appends a modal to the body on initialization. When a button (with the directive injected into it) is clicked this modal fires up. But I want the contents of this modal to be another component (In fact I want the modal to be the component). It seems that I can't initialize the component.

Here is a plunker of what I've done:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vEFCnVjGvMiJqb2Meprr?p=preview

I'm trying to make my-comp the template of my component

```
 '<div class="modal-body" #theBody>' 
            + '<my-comp></my-comp>' + 
 '</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**update for 2.0.0 final**

[**Plunker example >= 2.0.0**](https://plnkr.co/edit/akm7OPahe72Ex9i2ZXej?p=preview)

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ModalComponent, CompComponent],
  providers: [SharedService],
  entryComponents: [CompComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App, ModalComponent ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

```ts
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;

  cmp:ComponentRef;

  constructor(
    sharedService:SharedService, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    injector: Injector) {

    sharedService.showModal.subscribe(type => {
      if(this.cmp) {
        this.cmp.destroy();
      }
      let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
      this.cmpRef = this.theBody.createComponent(factory)
      $('#theModal').modal('show');
    });
  }

  close() {
    if(this.cmp) {
      this.cmp.destroy();
    }
    this.cmp = null;
  }
}
```

**Hint**

If one application change the state in `SharedService` or calls a method that causes an `Observable` to emit a value and the subscriber is in a different application then the emitter, the code in the subscriber is executed in the `NgZone` of the emitter.

Therefore when subscribing to an observable in `SharedService` use

```ts
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone, private sharedService:SharedService) {
    private sharedService.subscribe(data => this.zone.run() => {
      // event handler code here
    });
  }
}
```

For more details how to trigger change detection see [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

**original**

Dynamically added HTML is not processed by Angular and doesn't result in components or directives to be instantiated or added.

You can't add components outside Angulars root component (AppComponent) using <strike>`DynamicComponentLoader`</strike> (deprecated) `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` ([Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)).

I guess the best approach is to create a 2nd component outside Angulars root component is to call `bootstrap()` on each and use a shared service to communicate:

```ts
var sharedService = new SharedService();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(SharedService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
bootstrap(ModalComponent, [provide(SharedService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
```

[**Plunker example beta.17**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5kXNYf2PHdWE3V5y95FE?p=preview)
[**Plunker example beta.14**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mkZSM8dCP946baOt6uyw?p=preview)

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  showModal:Subject = new Subject();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-comp',
  template: `MyComponent`
})
export class CompComponent { }


@Component({
  selector: 'modal-comp',
  template: `
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="theModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog largeWidth" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="theModalLabel">The Label</h4></div>
        <div class="modal-body" #theBody>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (close)="close()">Close</button>
  </div></div></div></div>
`
})
export class ModalComponent {
  cmp:ComponentRef;
  constructor(sharedService:SharedService, dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    sharedService.showModal.subscribe(type => {
      if(this.cmp) {
        this.cmp.dispose();
      }
      dcl.loadIntoLocation(type, elementRef, 'theBody')
      .then(cmp => {
        this.cmp = cmp;
        $('#theModal').modal('show');
      });
    });
  }

  close() {
    if(this.cmp) {
      this.cmp.dispose();
    }
    this.cmp = null;
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>My First Attribute Directive</h1>
<button (click)="showDialog()">show modal</button>
<br>
<br>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next(CompComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's an issue if you want to call another modal inside the first instance. It just replaces the content, not creates another modal instance. Example here : https://plnkr.co/edit/5sjn25CV6QLbLIs2FcWp?p=preview

Comment: Ugh, it's a long time I had a look into these components

Comment: Yes I know, but I find it could be very useful, given that I'm stuck in a similar case : creating modals dynamically and call modal instance inside other modal instances