# try to use exportAs in angular2 component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is exportAs property defined for a component.
How can I access outside the component to a method of it?
I tried this example

```
<my-app #my="myApp">
loading...
</my-app>


<button (click)="my.displayMessage()" class="ui button">
  Display popup for message element
</button>
```

Here the component class

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

 @Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 providers: [],
 template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

  </div>
  `,
  directives: [],
   exportAs: "myApp"
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
   this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  displayMessage():void {
   console.log('called from component')
  }
}
```

Comment: That should work. What is the problem?

Comment: Cannot see the log. No error is shown

Comment: why do you need `exportAs` ? You can do the same thing by just writing `#my` instead of `#my="myApp"`

Comment: here it is an example of my problem. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/PAudXulH5VzecE9fYT1l?p=preview
as you could see the button outside the component does not work ...

Comment: exportAs is used for directives, see: https://plnkr.co/edit/IlLtBY7Ic9yKiRIpjukf?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supposed to work. You can't have any `#xxx`, `(xxx)` or any other kind of Angular binding outside the template of you root component (`App`).

You might be looking for something like [How to dynamically create bootstrap modals as Angular2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-component-in-angular-2/36566919?noredirect=1#comment60736661_36566919)

Answer (score 1):

exportAs is used for directives, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/IlLtBY7Ic9yKiRIpjukf?p=preview

```
@Directive({
  selector: "div",
  exportAs: "myDiv"
})
class MyDiv {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  toUpper() {
    return this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "text-transform", "uppercase");
  }

  toLower() {
    return this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "text-transform", "lowercase");
  }

  reset() {
    return this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "text-transform", "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`exportAs` was introduced, and has been available from Angular 5.

Angular 2,4 dont have it. Here is the link to [Angular.io blog for Angular5](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)