# Angular 2 bootstrap multi root component

Tags: angular

I would like to be able to boot multiple app root component into my index.html page. This was initially possible on angular 2 beta 0 - 15, but starting in beta 16, it is not working anymore. Please refer to this code
http://plnkr.co/edit/A7fyFUST9IdP1FriauXk?p=preview

```
please see plunker link above for the code
```

Hope somebody can modify the code to be able to work on angular 2 beta 17.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/APFwcpOGsMlOMVdGCkCI

It got much easier with newer versions:

```
bootstrap(Comp1);
bootstrap(Comp2);
```

Also here is a more advanced example of how to implement communication between applications:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aZqdJe3OZ8K2odHioWkB

Answer (score 5):

Just list all the components in `bootstrap` (and `declarations`)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ModalComponent, CompComponent],
  providers: [SharedService],
  entryComponents: [CompComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App, ModalComponent ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

See also [How to dynamically create bootstrap modals as Angular2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-html-component-in-angular-2) for a full example.