# Changing shared data between root modules

Tags: angular

I have two modules:

1st:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,

        SharedModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [
        FirstComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ FirstComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

2nd:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,

        SharedModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [
        ScndComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ ScndComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and shared module with static .forRoot()

```
@NgModule( {} )
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule    : SharedModule,
            providers   : [DumyService]
        }
    }
}
```

My DumyServise has some prop 'paramd' and I want to watch changes through modules

```
@Injectable()
export class DumyService {
    paramd : string;
}
```

In both components of modules (1st and 2nd) I have

```
private ds: DumyService
```

in constructors.

Then, let's say I have some onclick method in some component of first module component, that changes

```
clickToChangeParam() {
        this.ds.paramd = 'new value';
}
```

And I want to have this changes in both modules.
How can I handle that?

Comment: Why you want to have 2 root modules?

Comment: Because I need separate modules in different dom parts of my app.
And I dnt know, how I can run it without some component directive <somedir></somedir>

Comment: In angular1 it was easier to have root component in <html> tag.
In A2 I don't see that possibility.
A2 runs only through custom directive. Am I wrong?

Comment: For those who is still looking for the answer in 2020, with Angular 9, it introduces provideIn: 'platform' service which can share data between two root modules. FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454317/angular-9-platform-bootstrap-multiple-modules-run-multiple-applications-on-the

Answer (score 4):

There are several similar questions that will help you

- [Angular 2, communication between 2 apps running on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611144/angular-2-communication-between-2-apps-running-on-the-same-page)
- [How to dynamically create bootstrap modals as Angular2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-html-component-in-angular-2)
- [Angular 2 bootstrap multi root component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066421/angular-2-bootstrap-multi-root-component)

The main idea is create an instance of `SharedService` and use it as `extraProviders` when bootstrapping both components.

```
var sharedService = new SharedService();

platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: SharedService, useValue: sharedService }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: SharedService, useValue: sharedService }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule2)
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/J05PAHgdZiOVlXRzbZxK?p=preview)**

Maybe the best way is using one instance of platform:

```
var platform = platformBrowserDynamic([SharedService]);
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule2)
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ht4dYqLBnFSbACpN0rHi?p=preview)**

There is important thing(as @Günter said)

> The subscribing application needs to invoke change detection when it
>   receives a new value from the other Angular application because this
>   code is invoked in the zone of the sending Application.

That's why i am using `cd.detectChanges()` in examples above.

But i want to show one trick. We "can bootstrap module with known `Zone`". This way we needn't worry about the call of `detectChanges`. Both application will work within one `Zone`:

```
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic([SharedService]);
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>) => {
  const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);
  (<any>platform)._bootstrapModuleWithZone(AppModule2, [], zone); // private method is bad!!!
});
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XeoTl85e2XFcKDJNQggK?p=preview)**

Hope it helps someway!

Comment: I have tried to bootstrap two modules on the same page. It works as expected that they are have their own DI, NgZone, Routing, but I didn't find any official document about that, is there any side effect if we run bootstrap module more than one? Thanks.