# Most convenient way to let end user access another view without losing the current one

Tags: meteor, angular

Context

- Meteor + Angular2 app
- In the user flow it would be convenient let the end user access another component's view without losing the current one, for instance to search an information he needs.

Hypotheric solutions

- Allow the user to "pop-out" a 2nd view of another component in a popup
- Split the main app view into pane or use 'window-manager-style' to easily allow the display of multiple view ?

**How would you implement one of the solutions ?**

The simple case would be to have in one component's view, an include to the other, ok, that is feasable.

**However I am looking for a more flexible way to do it, i.e. I would like to be able to display any view of my app on the top of the one currently being visited.**

Comment: Does this need to be reflected in the URL? What is "window-manager-style"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
No this does not needs to be reflected in the URL.
Window manager style, meaning like a window manager (i.e. x11 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager).

Comment: You can do something like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36566919/217408. If you don't want to display the pop-up outside your primary Angular2 application it's even easier. Just use a shared service to communicate with the popup component, no need to boostrap the popup component individually.