# Why other components not showing up on index.html without <app-root>?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-components

I have just started learning Angular and working through some tutorials. My project is generated by Angular CLI. I have generated a new component called navbar on top of the component that was generated when I created the project and I was trying to see if navbar loads up on my index.html upon start up. My navbar shows up only when I have both app in the index.html file, for example:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</body>
```

If I remove app-root from index.html like so:

```
<body>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</body>
```

My navbar app is not showing it anymore. Is that something that has to do with the app-root component? Is it because it is a root component and it has to be included in index.html all the time?

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</body>

</html>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './component1/app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

navbar.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor() {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-lifecycle-interface
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must place the component selector inside app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

The **`<app-root>`** tag is where the bootstraped component be displayed ( which is the **`AppComponent`** by default). And usually you do not need more than 1 bootstraped component, so remove `NavbarComponent` from bootstrap in AppModule.

In a higher lever view, you can consider your app as a tree of components which it's root is the AppComponent, so the child of AppComponent must be place inside app.component.html, and the child of NavBarComponent for example must be place inside `navbar.component.html` .

Comment: Remove the NavbarComponent  from `boostrap ` in AppModule, i updated my answer

Comment: why angular team make the bootstrap as an array if that not correct ,the navbar here just a theme component so it 's no harm to move it outside but the angular app bootstrap from a single module check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add multiple component to bootstrap but they must be from the same module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, NavbarComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ,NavbarComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*index.html*

```
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<app-navbar>loading</app-navbar>
```

the angular app bootstrap from a single module like appmodule here

*main.ts*

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

  // Otherwise, log the boot error
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[demo ⚡⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fgok8)

Comment: Why after I remove 
<my-app>loading</my-app> from index.html
 
the navbar stops showing it's content ("navbar works!") instead it's showing "loading".

Comment: try like this   `bootstrap:    [ NavbarComponent  , AppComponent ]`

Comment: why you add any component to bootstrap list angula will look for that component selector an d throw an error even if any of the component is missing angular expect both component to be presint in the index.htm

Comment: so in your case the error throw before render the other component , I want to ask why do you try this why not just place the navbar in the app component and just bootstrap the app component

Comment: @malbarmavi, for example, if you need Render Angular component outside the main app like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526221/render-angular-component-outside-the-main-app

Answer (score 1):

Angular attempts to find app-root tag and throws error that you can see in console of browser something like this:

**Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at ha.selectRootElement (main-*.js)**

So rendering crashes, and navbar not showing

To avoid this issue add ngDoBootstrap method with conditionals to root app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule
{
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef)
  {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('app-root').length > 0)
    {
      appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent, 'app-root')
    }
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('app-navbar').length > 0)
    {
      appRef.bootstrap(NavbarComponent, 'app-navbar')
    }
  }
}
```