# Walkaround for using html rendered by server in an Angular application

Tags: angularjs, angular

We have, unfortunately a multi page application that we've been running with AngularJS. Now we're trying to migrate to Angular, as LTS approaches. We used to populate some part of our templates with the server data, rendering html as follows:

```html
<div class="some-class" ng-controller="SomeCtrl as ctrl">
    <div>...</div> <!-- Render some data from server -->
    <div sec:authorize="isRememberMe()">...</div> <!-- Use some Thymeleaf security tags -->
</div>
```

However, now that the components are already on the client, I'm looking for ways to manipulate templates with html rendered by the server. I've tried with `ng-content` which is useful for some cases, where I can bootstrap the component itself outside `app-root` like [Render Angular component outside the main app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526221/render-angular-component-outside-the-main-app). But when the template is in component itself, this ability is gone as well.

An alternative would be rendering the page as a non-Angular, conventional html page (not a component), and accessing some basic functionality that could be provided by Angular. The approach we used in the past as well allowed this, but I have no idea how I could achieve this.

Is there a walkaround for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Are you making HTTP calls from angular to server to get the data in the new implementation?

Comment: Yes, but for some parts, I cannot make RESTful requests. Like `sec:authorize="isRememberMe()"`.

Comment: Do you want to modify the HTML received from the server or display as it is ?

Comment: I want to render the HTML, and use JS/TS functionality in Component.

Comment: Is it possible for you to bring the entire HTML being rendered by server on the client side and make HTTP calls to get the necessary data and populate it on the client side.

This can give you quite a lot flexibility.

**Make child component for that particular part.

Comment: It is not possible, the whole question is about it...

Comment: I see. I can suggest you to go through these thread. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding


Another is 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: Markup added at runtime won't be processed by Angular. This comment has explained and provided useful reads for your case. I hope its helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/6682406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I come up with:

Render the `index.html` with Thymeleaf as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="partials/head :: head"></head>
<body>
    <th:block th:replace="partials/header :: header"></th:block>
    <app-root th:attr="some-property=${some.value.from.model}"></app-root>
    <th:block th:replace="partials/footer :: footer"></th:block>
</body>
```

This will render:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <app-root some-property="some-value"></app-root>
    ...
</body>
```

Create a `data.service.ts`:

```
  appData: any = {};
```

And in `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService,
            private element: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.appData['some-property'] = this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('some-property');
}
```

Finally in `sub.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someProperty = this.dataService.appData['some-property'];
}
```