# How to include the ts component in index.html file

Tags: angular, typescript

How to include the ts component in index.html file.I have been searching for it since a long time but no use can any one suggest help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
bootstrap(MyComponent)
```

to add a component to `index.html`. The selector of the component needs to match a tag in `index.html`

Comment: Gunter,here my problem is i have some html tags in index.html and i want to use binding to it from an external ts file.

Comment: Binding on root components is not supported.

Comment: How can we use shared services in index.html

Comment: [take a look on angular2 sample app](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-component-in-angular-2/36566919?noredirect=1#comment60736661_36566919

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are building angular 2 application and want to add  component to index.html file.

Create a class using component decorator and make sure you add `selector` property and template in decorator and bootstrap the app using angular's core bootstrap method with Component name.

```
main-component.ts
   import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   import { Component } from "@angular/core"

   @Component({
     selector: 'root',
     template: <div>It works!</div>
   })
   export class RootComponent{
    constructor(){}
   }

   bootstrap(RootComponent)

index.html

<body>
 <root></root>
</body>
```

bootstrap tells angular how to load your component since angular can be used to develop native mobile applications and web application you have use bootstrap method to initialize the application for a specific platform.

Comment: `Module '"../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic"' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.`

Answer (score 1):

None of those answers worked for me. However, the solution is very simple.

First create the component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-bar',
  templateUrl: './app-navigation-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-navigation-bar.component.css']
})
export class AppNavigationBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

}
```

Second, add the component to the app bootstrap:

```js
// File: app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, AppNavigationBarComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Third, use the component within the index.html:

```html
...
<body>
  <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
...
```