# Angular - Display a component in index.html

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

I am trying to display a `create-form-component` from the index.html.

I have:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BirdCreateFormComponent } from './create-form/create-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [BirdCreateFormComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

And in index.html:

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  <create-form></create-form>
</body>
```

But the `<create-form>` tag was ignored - why?

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-56eljz?file=src%2Fcreate-form%2Fcreate-form.component.html,src%2Fcreate-form%2Fcreate-form.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftsconfig.app.json).

I am new to Angular so a narrative around the answer would be great.

Comment: There is an error in the console, the Angular application does not load properly. But even after fixing that error, the create form component is used in `index.html` outside Angular context, this doesn't work. Further reading: https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include the ts component in index.html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803730/how-to-include-the-ts-component-in-index-html-file)

Comment: Take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245404/structure-of-an-angular-project-file-index-html/75245866#75245866). See that you have only one tag. The component can have severals components, a component and a router-outlet, severals router-outlet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `App` is the starting (root) component of the Angular Application. Thus you can't render the `BirdCreateFormComponent` in the index.html, but you need through `App` to render `BirdCreateFormComponent`.
2. You are mixing up the `NgModule` and `Component` for `App`. As starting from Angular 15.2, it supports bootstrapping standalone component without the root module.

If you are looking for bootstrapping Standalone component solution, you need to build the components as `standalone`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, BirdCreateFormComponent],
  template: `
    <create-form></create-form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  ...
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'create-form',
  templateUrl: './create-form.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  styleUrls: ['./create-form.component.css']
})
export class BirdCreateFormComponent {
   ...
}
```

Reference: [Migrate an existing Angular project to standalone](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration)

[Demo Bootstrapping Standalone Component @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lciv74?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

---

Or if you are looking for bootstrapping module, you need the root module and bootstrap it.

```
import {
  BrowserModule,
  platformBrowser,
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BirdCreateFormComponent } from './create-form/create-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [App, BirdCreateFormComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [App],
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowser()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <create-form></create-form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  ...
}
```

[Demo Bootstrapping Module @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3k8hxh?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Bottom sample: shouldn't the `BirdCreateFormComponent` be in the `bootstrap` array too?

Comment: Hi, no, because in the showing example I am using the `App` as the startup component. And in the HTML template of `App` render the `BirdCreateFormComponent` with `<create-form></create-form>`.