# Angular 2: How to dynamically create ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, components

I'm trying to create modal service with ability to show arbitrary modal.
Currently, to create dynamic component, I'm storing placeholder for it in view:

```
 <div #container></div>
 ...
 @ViewChild("dialogContainer", {read: ViewContainerRef})
 dialogContainer:ViewContainerRef;
```

And than creating component:

```
let factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Dialog);
this.componentReference = this.dialogContainer.createComponent(factory);
```

Is there way to move all this logic out of component to service, with ability to create/remove view container in body, or any other DOM element?

Comment: i need genereate container like this  ````<div #itemId *ngfor="let item in tems">``` and get respective id viewcontainer reference

Comment: i need load mutiple dynamic components in mutiple dynammic  containers

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-html-component-in-angular-2

Comment: What do you mean by *modal service*? In the code you provided the template variable does not match the `ViewChild` parameter. I also do not see how the current title relates to the issue described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It dosen't create ViewContainerRef but It helps you create dynamically a popup window as separate Component.

I created plunker example for you, and I didn't embed it here because stackowerflow code snippet dosen't support all features which I need in order to create example :) 
http://embed.plnkr.co/XFQAAHDAyrRAih3RTvHH/

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question instead of just linking a Plunker. It'f for a reason that a Plunker link on its own is prevented.

Comment: I also don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: It does solve his problem, because I had same problem.

Comment: Right, didn't properly read the question. The question is actually not about "How to dynamically create ViewContainerRef". The answer still doesn't contain the relevant code parts directly.

Comment: Right but when you look code sample from subject you can see it that he needs it for creating popup and I give him path to be able to solve his problem.

Comment: And example which i provide is doing exactly that.

Comment: Well, it's more convenient approach, but still uses predefined placeholder and logic inside component.