# Angular 2 insert a @Component into the DOM of another component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: '<b>Content</b>',
})
export class TestPage {
  constructor() {}
}
```

And I have another component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
})
export class MainPage {

  constructor() {}

  putInMyHtml() {

  }
}
```

main.html:

```
<p>stuff</p>
<div> <!-- INSERT HERE --> </div>
```

How can I dynamically insert my `TestPage` component into the area where `<!--INSERT HERE-->` is programatically, like when I run `putInMyHtml`.

I tried editing the DOM and inserting `<test-component></test-component>` but it doesn't display the content text from TestPage's template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't initialize dynamically appended (HTML) component in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566698/cant-initialize-dynamically-appended-html-component-in-angular-2)

Comment: That is the correct solution. Did you get an error message either in your browser console or your compiler?

Comment: @Martin there isn't an error, it remains as <test-component> in the DOM without angular rendering the template.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/HMXV6WM4jd8yZiOq9rJR?p=preview)** with the **ComponentFactoryResolver**

Firstly you have to register your dynamic component `TestPage` properly

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainPage, TestPage],
  entryComponents: [TestPage]
})
```

Alternative option

Declare **dynamic-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({})
export class DynamicModule {
  static withComponents(components: any[]) {
    return {
      ngModule: DynamicModule,
      providers: [
        { 
          provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
          useValue: components,
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and import it in **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, DynamicModule.withComponents([TestPage]) ],
  declarations: [ MainComponent, TestPage ]
})
```

Then your `MainPage` component might look as follows:

```
import { ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="putInMyHtml()">Insert component</button>
    <p>stuff</p>
    <div>
       <template #target></template> 
    </div>
  `
})
export class MainPage {
  @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  putInMyHtml() {
    this.target.clear();
    let compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(TestPage);

    this.target.createComponent(compFactory);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, i tried so many things, this is a headache, Angular keeps changing

Comment: yurzui  - I tried modifying your plunker to meet my needs, but my scenario is different enough I got stuck - I forked your plunker - can you maybe give me some input - as you clearly kno wwhat's going on. if you can - thx.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740046/angular-5-loading-a-component-into-a-div

Comment: Thank you sir. A really nice and simple solution. It is by far the best solution I have found so far.

Answer (score 1):

If both components are in the same module, make sure they were both declared first:

**MyModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestPage, MainComponent]
})
```

If they are in different modules, make sure you've exported `TestPage` and imported it into the module where you load `MainComponent`:

**TestPageModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestPage],
  exports: [TestPage]
})
```

**MainComponent**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  imports: [TestPage]
})
```