# Ionic2 Angular2 - How to add component to a div with TypeScript

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have created a component "test" with Ionic 2 CLI, and was wondering how do I add this component dynamically to the **#componentContainer** **HomePage** from **HomePage.ts**.

Here is test component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello TestComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }
}
```

And here is my HomePage:

```
<ion-content padding>
      <div #componentContainer>

      </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the HomePage.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Can't find the answer anywhere...

Comment: Try to follow these links 

http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571013/4667424

Comment: Why you need to add it  from HomePage.ts. You can do with tag `<test></test>`

Comment: Thanks for the link Jonnysai, that was what I needed :)