# How to place dynamically created component in desired #target

Tags: angular

I am creating Quora/facebook like comment functionality. But comments can go to any depth. 
Following is my template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items let i = index">

    <!-- some html code -->
   <button(click)="addComment(item.id,i)">
    <div>
            <ng-template #target></ng-template>           
    </div>

   </li>
</ul>
```

I am creating dynamic component and
for this i have refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571013) answer.

```
export class myDynamicComponent {
     @ ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef; 
     constructor(private replyService: ReplyService, private cfr: 
     ComponentFactoryResolver){}

    public addComment(Id:any, index:any){
       this.commentService.getContent(Id)
              .subscribe(data => {
     let compFactory = 
     this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(myDynamicComponent);              
     let instance=this.target.createComponent(compFactory).instance;
        instance.items=data ;
  }
 }
}
```

So i am creating dynamic component in #target. I have multiple  because it is generating in the loop. 
The problem with this is that newly created component get attached to first #target and not the current (clicked) #target.

What is the way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items let i = index">

    <!-- some html code -->
   <button(click)="addComment(item.id,i)">
    <div>
            <ng-template #target></ng-template>           
    </div>

   </li>
```

extract it to separate component like:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items let i = index">

   <my-button-click-comment-something-component [sendToIt]="whateverYouNeed">
   </my-button-click-comment-something-component>

</li>
```

and then in your `my-button-click-comment-something-component` do dynamic component creation and handling.

Comment: actually my 'my-button-click-comment-something-component' is the 'myDynamicComponent'.  I need to create n number of components. There is no limit of the depth for comments.  I followed your suggestions but still can not atach newly created dynamic component to current directive/#target.

Comment: i don't think so. The whole point is that `*ngFor` and `#target` are not in the same template.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your comment?  Because even if I separate out component I still need to load future components in <my-button-click-comment-something-component [sendToIt]="whateverYouNeed">
   </my-button-click-comment-something-component>

Comment: yes exactly but then you have just one `#target` where you need to make instance of your component