# Angular 5 loading a component into a div

Tags: angular

Looking thru a bunch of posts, it looks like a fair amount of people have this question, in one for or another. But I don't see an answer. so I am going to repost, in hopes of some new eyes getting on it.

The question - how to load a component into a div when something is clicked.
My specific scenario - I have a "sub-nav" with a dozen forms on it, I want to avoid making a route for each of these forms, I would also like to avoid loading all 12 forms in a 'hidden' state (like one does using tabs). I think I want a new component to be lazy loaded into the "main content" div only when a user selects it from a list.

I have modified a plunker (from https://plnkr.co/edit/HMXV6WM4jd8yZiOq9rJR?p=preview) so it represents 3 form components, and a sub-nav component, and the main page (which wound be something like domain/forms/). such that once a user got here, they could pick a form and have it appear in what here would be

https://plnkr.co/edit/WpvAYa6V1PWVicvMzv6e?p=preview

2 issues exist 
1) this.target isn't known to the putInMyHtml() function, so nothing changes
2) it was only working with the "TestPage" being passed, I didn't know how to pass a dynamic var.

Hope this makes sense.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { DynamicModule } from './dynamic.module';


// mock form components ---------------------
@Component({
    template: '<b>Form 1</b>',
})
export class TestPage {}

@Component({
    template: '<b>Form 2</b>',
})
export class TestPage2 {}

@Component({
    template: '<b>Form 3</b>',
})
export class TestPage3 {}


// sub nav page ---------------------
@Component({
    selector: 'sub-Nav',
    template: `
        <a (click)="putInMyHtml(1)">Insert component</a> |
        <a (click)="putInMyHtml(2)">Insert component</a> |
        <a (click)="putInMyHtml(3)">Insert component</a> |
        <p>Some instructions</p>
    `    
})
export class SubNav {

    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    putInMyHtml(n) {
        this.target.clear();
        let compFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(TestPage);
        this.target.createComponent(compFactory);
    }

}

// main page ---------------------
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <sub-Nav></sub-Nav>
        <div>
             <template #target></template> 
        </div>
    `
})
export class MainPage {}


@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule, 
        DynamicModule.withComponents([TestPage]) 
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        MainPage, 
        TestPage,
        TestPage2,
        TestPage3, 
        SubNav 
    ],
    bootstrap: [ MainPage ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dbapnheAKqxrE2hYhgEm?p=preview

Comment: perfect thanks yurzui