# In Angular 5, how to get access to dynamically added child components from parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic + Angular 5 project.

I need to dynamically load some components. Following the [Dynamic Component Loader Example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) in the Angular documentation I am able to successfully load components and displayed them.

I have a need, however, to be able to loop through the loaded components.

I can easily maintain my own list of components in the parent as I create and destroy the child components but it seems to me that that's ugly and not the "Angular Way".

After much experimentation and research it seems that I cannot use @ViewChildren to access dynamically added components since they have their own views. [ViewChildren not finding Dynamically components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102427/viewchildren-not-finding-dynamic-components)

Is this correct?

I am able to use viewContainerRef.get() to iterate over the child views and retrieve ViewRefs. But there doesn't seem to be a way to get a reference to the component given a ViewRef?

I notice the 'rootNodes' property of the ViewRef however that property is not documented in the Angular docs [View Ref](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewRef) However, it is documented in the EmbeddedViewRef docs [Embedded View Ref](https://angular.io/api/core/EmbeddedViewRef) but that still doesn't seem to give me access to the component.

So the question is when I have a parent that dynamically adds child components how can I from the parent loop through the child components (so I can call one of my methods in the child)? My suspicion is that I am missing something stupid simple, have some fundamental misconception, or that there is a different pattern that I should be using.

I've modified the Dynamic Component Loader example to highlight what I am trying to do.[Modified Dynamic Component Loader](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvuafm)

Comment: I'm just wondering why not store created component in a member and use it later, like `let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory); this.newComponent = componentRef;` and then in `logViewChildren()` do `console.log(this.newComponent.instance.data);`?

Comment: Yea, that's my fallback which I'm implementing at the moment.

My intent is to try to understand Angular thinking. It seems to me it should be possible without having to keep a separate stack of components, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: Its the angular way that that dynamic components should communicate by a shared service hosted on the parent and injected on the child. I personally find managing the ref.instance to be perfectly fine. (your backup solution)

Comment: @pwwpche Your recommendation is great. Very simple and keeps the code easy to follow and maintain going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I thought about this and a clean way to do this (in my opinion), is to pass create a property on the parent component, such as `parentContext` and to pass the data or method into this object.

**Example - in parent component, you can even pass a method into your child component and it will run within the context of the parent.**:

```
  gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
    this.entry.clear();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicModalChildComponent);
    this.dynamicModalComponentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
    this.dynamicModalComponentRef.instance.hero = hero;
    // Pass parent context to child in order to close modal hierarchically (parent/child component relationship).
    // This approach is less verbose and makes it easier to unit test than a service in my opinion.
    this.dynamicModalComponentRef.instance.parentContext = () => this.destroyComponent();
}
```