# How to emit event from dynamically loaded modal to parent

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

I have a modal that is dynamically created from a component, this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  showModal:Subject<any> = new Subject();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-comp',
  template: `MyComponent dataToPass: {{dataToPass}}, dataToPass2: {{dataToPass2}}

            <button (click)="updateData()">Update data</button>`
})
export class CompComponent {
    @Output() setupDataUpdated = new EventEmitter();    
  private dataToPass2;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dataToPass2 = this.dataToPass + ' hello';
  }

  updateData() {
    console.log('data updated');
    this.setupDataUpdated.emit('emitted_value');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-comp',
  template: `
  <div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="theModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog largeWidth" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{theHeader}}</h4></div>
        <div class="modal-body" #theBody (setupDataUpdated)="updateSetupData($event)">
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (close)="close()">Close</button>
  </div></div></div></div>
`
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;

  theHeader: string = '';
  dataToPass: string = '';
  cmpRefBody:ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    sharedService:SharedService, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    injector: Injector) {

    sharedService.showModal.subscribe(data => {
      if(this.cmpRef) {
        this.cmpRef.destroy();
      }
      let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.type);
      this.cmpRef = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmpRef.instance.dataToPass = data.dataToPass;
      this.dataToPass = data.dataToPass;
      this.theHeader = data.title;
      console.log(data.title);
      console.log(data.dataToPass);
      $('#theModal').modal('show');
    });
  }

  close() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.cmpRef = null;
  }

    updateSetupData(data) {
        console.log('update data');
        console.log(data);
    }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <button (click)="showDialog()">show modal</button>
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  showDialog() {
    this.sharedService.showModal.next({'type': CompComponent, 'title': 'titolo1', 'dataToPass': 'dataToPass'});
  }
}
```

(referrer: [Angular 2 modals shared between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248272/angular-2-modals-shared-between-components?noredirect=1#comment69722715_41248272)).

As you can see, I was trying to emit an event `setupDataUpdated` from modal child component, but modal parent component seems not to see the event.
Do you know why? Where's my mistake?

Comment: Please accept an answer or leave a comment so that this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually subscribe to your `EventEmitter` as below:

```
this.cmpRef.instance.setupDataUpdated.subscribe((data) => this.updateSetupData(data));
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zKWhlilZbjd2gOMEvtyl?p=preview)**

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but I think it's implemented in reverse. You've added the subscriber to the modal component. It should be in the component that calls the modal, now? Also, Plunker's broken.

Comment: @isherwood Fixed plunker